# How can I test gloves for long ride comfort?

Tags: gloves

Preface: for about 15 years I have used always the same pair of gloves, which worked as a charm. Since they started to show their age and that version is since long time no longer produced, I looked for another pair.

I tried one, which had a padding in the palm, and they felt comfortable on my hands. Only after wearing them a few hours on the ride I noticed the padding, pushing on my palms, made my hands numb, so I had no other choice than not wearing them.

Is there a way to assess gloves comfort in the few minutes one can try them in a shop?

Comment: wow, 15 years for gloves is impressive!

Comment: About 30 years ago I bought a pair of gloves that were just about perfect.  Unfortunately, they only lasted 15 years, and I've not been able to find a decent pair since.   When everyone went with gel filling that wrecked them, for long-distance riding.

Comment: Very hard to assess how any clothing will feel after a few hours riding. Maybe look for gloves with approximately the same type and amount of padding as you old ones?

Answer (score 1):

When testing for something, you wanna make sure you are providing the similar environment for testing as for use.

Exhale some warm moist air on handle-like things, make sure you warm your hands up to the maximum extent by rubbing vigorously, hold them firmly for next 5 or so mins (doesn't matter riding or not).

This'll let you judge 3 things basically:

- How they deal with sweat, is the grip impacted!
- Is the cushioning sufficient, because we generally don't make such tight grips continuously while riding.
- When you remove them and touch their palm side with bare hands, their temperature will tell you about material too. if they're properly ventilated or not.

Comment: good points, but none of them address the "make my hands numb" I am struggling with